# Access file size hugely increase when inserting some logo(icon)

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have an empty database with size about 3MB (with some tables and forms).
Then I insert some icon to make it more user friendly but the file size increase to 17-19 MB after I saved it.
I tried to create new access file then import all the tables and forms (with icon) but the file size is about the same (17-19) MB.

When I create another access file and import all the tables and forms (I delete all the icons in all forms) and the file size reduce to about 1-2 MB only.
I'm saving it in access 2002-2003 file (.mdb). The actual size of those icons are about 3-4KB only.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: How many forms are you talking about, and what is the original file format of the 3-4KB icon files? (For example, are they `.jpg` files?)

Comment: @GordThompson about 15 form.the original file size of the database without any icons on the forms just less than 4MB but increase to more than 10MB after i insert those icons. yes they are.jpg image with actual size of 3-4 KB.